# Relationship field & variables outside of product form

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Trying to access price of some store items in a relationship field.
The name of my store field is `shop_product_settings`

I'm trying to access the price variable without using the form tag, however, it doesn't seem to work when the items are being access through a relationship field.

```
  {class_recommended_products limit="2" }
    {class_recommended_products:title}"
    {class_recommended_products:shop_product_settings:price}
    {class_recommended_products:shop_main_image}
  {/class_recommended_products}
```

Comment: What version of Store and EE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {relationship_field parse="inward"}
        {exp:store:product entry_id="{relationship_field:entry_id}" disable_form="yes" disable_javascript="yes"}
            {price}
        {/exp:store:product}
    {/relationship_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

That may not be possible. Store takes advantage of EE's internal parsing to display the special `price` variables inside the product details tag.

I have not tried this myself, but it may not be possible to use the fieldtype parameters inside a relationship tag like that. Instead, would need to use the `{exp:store:product}` tag to get the product details.